# Seeing if an infinite loop in C++ will occur

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

Will the following code result in infinite loop?

```
  x=0;
  y=0;

  while(x<100)
  {
    minnum=100;
    maxnum=100;
    while(y<150)
    {
    if(random[x][y]<minnum)
      {
      minnum=random[x][y];
      minX=x;
      minY=y;
      y++;
      }
    else if(random[x][y]>maxnum)
      {
      maxnum=random[x][y];
      maxX=y;
      maxY=y;
      y++;
      }
    }
    x++;
    y=0;
  }
```

Comment: Whats the problem? What did you expect it to do, what does it do? Is this homework?

Comment: This is pretty bad code. :) I would move the y=0 initializer to the top of the loop, use two for loops, and add comments about the data structure you are iterating over. Also, as mentioned below, fixing the maxX=y bug could help. your else if, should probably just be an else. Y++ can be moved out of the inner ifs. And if you want minnum and maxnum to be the minimum or maximum for the entire array, you need to move their initialization outside of the outerloop. You should also initialize them to the compiler defines for minimum and maximum for your data structure.

Comment: Both loops could be more succinctly written as for loops - for(x = 0; x < 100; x++) - avoiding scattering the loop controls around the code. It looks like you end up recording the value and position of the element of random that has the smallest value less than 100 and the largest value greater than 100. It is odd, though, that you reset minnum and maxnum inside the outer loop; you could end up with maxX, maxY from one row and a maxnum value from another row of the matrix. Written with for loops, you'd always increment y, preventing an infinite loop (but I cribbed that from @fbrereto).

Answer (score 9):

If both `random[x][y]<minnum` and `random[x][y]>maxnum` are `false`, you'll never exit out of the inner loop. More specifically if `random[x][y] == 100` you're toast the first time through.

As a related question, what behavior do you see when you debug the source you've posted?

Comment: This is not correct - it doesn't matter what the values of either of the conditions of the if-then-else are ... it is still an infinite loop. y is reset to 0 each iteration of the loop, so it never goes above 0 (and never reaches 150)

Comment: @Larry Watanabe: better than 'ignore my comment' is 'you delete your own erroneous comment'.

Answer (score 2):

There were many good answers to the original question, but even so none of them will work! That's because there is a dutifully-preserved typo in the second "if" block -- should read

```
maxX = x; // not y!
maxY = y;
```

Comment: Also, it doesn't matter since [min|max][X|Y] is never used other than being assigned to. They're not causing any infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

If neither of the `if` and `else if` in the inner loop is satisfied, you never increment `y`, thus making that inner loop undending. Looks like the `y++` should be OUTSIDE of any conditional statements.

Comment: This is not correct - it doesn't matter what the values of either of the conditions of the if-then-else are ... it is still an infinite loop. y is reset to 0 each iteration of the loop, so it never goes above 0 (and never reaches 150)

Comment: Sorry, mislead by the formatting - ignore my comment (My mind only works when i have 4 char indentation :)

Answer (score 1):

This will enter an infinite loop any time your array value is between minnum and maxnum. Initially, this is only at 100. One the second pass, is is the difference between the minimum and maximum value you have seen. If the value is 3000 for instance, you will have minnum of 100 and maxnum of 3000. Now, any number between 100 and 3000 (inclusive) will cause an infinite loop. See other answers for how to fix the code.

Jacob

Answer (score 0):

On the inner `while` loop, if `random[x][y] == minnum`, then `y` will never be incremented and the program will go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

If `minnum <= random[x][y] <= maxnum` then `y` is never incremented in the inner loop. Probably you should increment `y` in any case, even if none of the if-conditions are met. Best move the `y++` outside of the `if`s before the closing brace of the `while` loop.

You could also use `for`-loops to iterate over the possible values for `x` and `y`, which would reduce the probability of such mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If `random[x][y]` is ever exactly 100, this will loop infinitely, since it never does anything in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my vision of this cycle - some conserns about how to write "good" code (from my point of view - I'm really not a guru in programming) - not essential to follow them, but I think they are not so bad.

```
  // It's a good rule - to initialize minimum and maximum with one
  // (any) element from the array you will be working with
  minnum=random[0][0];
  maxnum=random[0][0];

  // This is my hamble opinion but I'll prefer to have variables for array sizes
  sizeX=100;
  sizeY=150;

  // Cannot you use for instead of while?
  for(x = 0; x < sizeX; ++x)
      for(y = 0; y < sizeY; ++y)
      {
          if(random[x][y] < minnum)
          {
              minnum = random[x][y];
              minX = x;
              minY = y;
          }
          else if(random[x][y] > maxnum)
          {
              maxnum = random[x][y];
              maxX = x;
              maxY = y;
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only promote y when random is smaller than minnum or larger than maxnum, creating a problem where neither occur.

But why do you promote it only if those conditions occur?
You want y to be promoted regardless of those conditions.

You'll probably want to change to:

```
while(y<150)
{
if(random[x][y]<minnum)
  {
  minnum=random[x][y];
  minX=x;
  minY=y;
  }
else if(random[x][y]>maxnum)
  {
  maxnum=random[x][y];
  maxX=y;
  maxY=y;
  }
  y++;
}
```

This way both y and x are always promoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your **while** loops with **for** loops, your code will make more sense, be less error-prone, and this will solve your infinite loop problem:

```
minnum=100;
maxnum=100;
for (int x = 0; x<100; x++)
{
  for(int y=0; y<150; y++)
  {
    if(random[x][y]<minnum)
    {
      minnum=random[x][y];
      minX=x;
      minY=y;
    }
    else if(random[x][y]>maxnum)
    {
      maxnum=random[x][y];
      maxX=y;
      maxY=y;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if professors in universities now should know that students can go online like this and get the answers?

Anyway like everyone been saying if random[x][y]==100, then this will always be in the inside loop.